# Convert vector of ddmmyyhhmmss strings to date

Tags: r

Fairly straight forward, i dont usually dabble in R. Making it a little provoking when the usual tricks dont seem to work.

I understand that `strftime` is the datetime parser, so i tried that with no luck, assuming its the format to blame.

```
datetime <- strftime(dat24$DateAndTime, tz="GMT", format="%d%m%Y%H%M%S")
print(head(datetime))
Output >> [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

i tried the `as.POSIXct`, well it yields a result, but a pretty wrong result. again I'm guessing its the missing format to blame, and maybe the origin.

```
datetime <-as.POSIXct(dat24$DateAndTime, origin = "1970-01-01 01:01.01", tz = "GMT")

print(head(dat24$DateAndTime))
Output >> [1] 240515055655 240515055757 240515055857 240515055958 240515060058 240515060200

print(head(datetime))
Output >> [1] "9591-08-15 02:41:55 GMT" "9591-08-15 02:43:37 GMT" "9591-08-15 02:45:17 GMT" "9591-08-15 02:46:58 GMT" "9591-08-15 03:55:18 GMT" "9591-08-15 03:57:40 GMT"
```

So the question is fairly simple, how do i convert this list?

Comment: do: `as.list(datetime)`

Comment: you could try `dmy_hms` from `lubridate` ... otherwhise give an example of `dat24$DateAndTime`

Comment: or try: `library(lubridate); as.list(dmy_hms(dat24$DateAndTime))`

Comment: what's with the `as.list` @ManishSaraswat?

Comment: @Val I suppose the question wants to convert the date output to list.

Comment: I see, say's right there on the bottom

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Just post some  `dat24$DateAndTime` and you'll receive sensible help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it into an answer ...

You can use `dmy_hms` from lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)

dts <- sprintf('%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d',sample(1:28,10,T),sample(1:12,10,T),sample(2010:2018,10,T),sample(0:23,10,T),sample(0:59,10,T),sample(0:59,10,T))

dts[1]
# [1] "27022016185346"


dmy_hms(dts)
# [1] "2016-02-27 18:53:46 UTC" "2016-05-05 07:13:08 UTC" "2016-01-27 08:34:16 UTC" "2017-02-19 15:11:15 UTC"
# [5] "2016-09-01 20:59:21 UTC" "2012-03-12 01:30:15 UTC" "2014-12-06 06:49:51 UTC" "2016-01-18 17:38:44 UTC"
# [9] "2010-12-26 01:51:51 UTC" "2010-06-17 08:41:44 UTC"
```